# Arrastar TreeViewItem para Form

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Estou montando um projeto com *FireMonkey*. Neste, quero arrastar um TreeViewItem para a área vazia do formulário e então executar outras opções... O famoso `DragDrop`.
Não estou conseguindo fazer isso e nem encontrei documentação a respeito.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fazer? Ou alguém poderia indicar uma documentação clara e completa?

Comment: Cara, eu nunca vi drag/drop nativo. Quando tive que montar algo do tipo, foram com os componentes da DexExpress. Se pá, dá pra dar uma olhada lá pra ter uma ideia.